# Android Emulator and adb problems

Tags: android, emulation

I'm having a problem in that whenever I start a emulator, either manually through the command line, or when debugging from Eclipse, it is never recognized by adb, i.e. 'adb devices' will not list it. I have to manually kill and restart adb every time I want to recognize a new emulator. Surely, something is wrong here?

(I'm on Vista 64-bit)

Comment: I would agree that something is wrong, though off the top of my head I can't quite figure out what. If you were having problems with devices, I'd point to drivers, but that should not be an issue with the emulator. Are you sure you only have one copy of the Android SDK installed? I could see problems like this if you had two, and adb was coming from one and the emulator from another.

Comment: Well, the emulator and the adb and definitely running off the same SDK location as if I kill-server and restart in the same folder, the emulator then appears correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems prior to SDK Tools, Revision 5. The problems are gone ever since I updated to Revision 5 and then 6.

There is one line in the [SDK Tools, Revision 5 release notes](http://developer.android.com/sdk/tools-notes.html) that might be related

- *"Fixes issue with 64-bit JVM on Windows."*

Comment: Thanks, I've checked I am on Revision 6 though